# Clarifications on managing orientations in UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, orientation

I have a configuration like the following:

```
UINavigationController
    -> ViewController
```

where `ViewController` is the root view controller for the navigation controller.

`ViewController` can present modally another view controller, `ModalViewController`, like the following.

```
self.presentViewController(modalViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Within `ModalViewController` I override the following method. The modal view controller in fact can be presented only in `Landscape` mode.

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .Landscape
}
```

I then override `ViewController`'s method for responding to orientation changes.

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)        
    print("Size is \(size)")
}
```

What I noticed is that if the modal view controller is presented, the `print` in `ViewController` is logged only if `ModalViewController` is in `Landscape` mode, while it is no logged in `Portrait`. In other words, while I rotate the device, `ModalViewController` should be able to display `Landscape` orientations only. Under the hood, even if `ViewController` is not visible (and the device is in `Portrait`), this controller should be able to respond to size changes. This is not the case since I cannot see the `print` log.

Use case:

if `ModalViewController` is not visible this is the print log

```
Size is (1024.0, 768.0)
Size is (768.0, 1024.0)
Size is (1024.0, 768.0)
Size is (768.0, 1024.0)
```

when `ModalViewController` is presented modally

```
Size is (1024.0, 768.0)
Size is (1024.0, 768.0)
```

Is this one the correct behaviour? My goal is to respond to orientation changes for the `ViewController` even if (when `ModalViewController` is opened) the device is in Portrait mode. Any clue?

**Edit**

Based on **matt** comment.

> If ViewController is not the frontmost view controller it has no business "responding to orientation changes". You've merely stumbled across an implementation detail or edge case in which you should have no interest.

`ViewController` is a complex controller that acts as a parent view controller. It has two children: `PortraitViewController` and `LandscapeViewController`. These controllers are swapped in `viewWillTransitionToSize` method. Whenever `ModalViewController` is not visible (not presented) the swapping works in the correct manner. On the contrary, when `ModalViewController` is presented, the swapping runs just for `Landscape` mode (see logs above).

Comment: I don't understand: "only if ModalViewController is in Landscape mode, while it is no logged in Portrait."  I thought you said that ModalVC is always in landscape.

Comment: @danh when `ModalViewController` is in portrait `ViewController` should receive the `viewWillTransitionToSize`. In this way I can adjust constraint based on that size.

Comment: @danh I added some additional details. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: Hi @LorenzoBoaro - I don't understand why you care about this. If ViewController is not the frontmost view controller it has no business "responding to orientation changes". You've merely stumbled across an implementation detail or edge case in which you should have no interest.

Comment: @matt Thanks for the reply. I added an edit to explain better the situation. Thanks.

Comment: @LorenzoBoaro That's great but if there's a modal view controller's view in front, who cares whether we got swapped, as there is nothing to see? (I'm not being difficult, I'm just trying to hone my understanding of the issue.)

Comment: @LorenzoBoaro And in any case if there's a modal view controller's view covering the screen, your ViewController's view has been ripped right out of the interface, so there is nothing _to_ swap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me as if you're just trying to do something at the wrong time. When the modal view controller is dismissed and your view controller's view is about to reappear, you'll get plenty of warning (including `appear` and `layout` events) and you can do whatever needs doing, based on the current orientation, before your view becomes visible to the user.